# CiviCRM installation (Backdrop) incomplete

Tags: installation, backdrop

Backdrop CMS: 1.16.1
CiviCRM: 5.25.0
php 7.3.17
Shared host (Civihosting)

Following installation of CiviCRM on fresh install of Backdrop, I started the CiviCRM configuration process, but was unable to save the first set of questions (Language and currency). I then noticed that I don't have the CiviCRM menu.
No errors appeared during install after providing correct database information.
Following System Status: Error link in footer leads to blank page.
Feeling a little foolish - something very basic awry, methinks...

Screenshot:
[image: illustration of civi dashboard page after 1st install]

Comment: If this is a new install, is your DNS setup correctly?  Civihosting give you a temporary DNS name but if your configured URL doesn't match the actual servername you'll get problems like this.

Comment: Thanks, Aidan. No issues with DNS that I can see. As an experiment, I deleted site and databases and reinstalled using Civihosting server pseudonym... same result. Testing on a couple of other host platforms.

Comment: Anything in the logs or console or ?

Comment: Look at your browser's Developer Tools and see if there are requests failing

Comment: Aidan and Laryn: many thanks for suggestions. I will return to this soon, but in the meantime didn't want to be impolite and ignore you. Will let you know what I find.

Comment: same here with CiviCRM 5.36.1 on BACKDROP 1.83 (via MAMP 6.3 PHP 7.4.12)

Comment: Got the same issue - did you ever figure out why?

Comment: Same question I asked above: Anything in the logs or console or ?